# Switch run configurations while running

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hotswap

In Eclipse, is it possible to switch an application that is `Run`ning (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) to `Debug` (<kbd>F11</kbd>) mode?

I know that while the program is running in debug mode, it's possible to change the code without stopping it (hot code replace). I'm hoping that there's something similar for run configurations.

Suggestions?

Comment: There is no way to switch between Run mode and debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, unless you start with some command line switches, which means you basically are really starting in debug mode but no connection to a client at startup but allow attaching a debug client (possibly remotely) later.

Why not always start it in Debug?

Hot code replace is part of the debug interface (JPDA) (since java 1.4) so not doable in normal run mode.

Hot code replace introduction:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/enhancements.html#hotswap